# How to catch a Divide by 0 error message in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

So I am making a calculator for visual studio 2012. It is like 95% done with the exception of one small thing. I need to display a error message when a user tries to divide by 0. I have tried searching online and cannot find a for sure way of doing this. How exactly do you do it? My code is below
Option Explicit On
Public Class Calculator

```
Dim FirstNumber As Single
Dim SecondNumber As Single
Dim AnswerNumber As Single
Dim ArithmeticProcess As String
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 1
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 2
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 3
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 4
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 5
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 6
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 7
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 8
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 9
End Sub

Private Sub btn0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnDecimal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDecimal.Click
    txtAnswer.Text = txtAnswer.Text & "."
End Sub

Private Sub btnPlus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Text = "0"
    ArithmeticProcess = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub btnMinus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMinus.Click


    FirstNumber = Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Text = "0"
    ArithmeticProcess = "-"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnMultiply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Text = "0"
    ArithmeticProcess = "X"
End Sub

Private Sub btnDivide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDivide.Click
    FirstNumber = Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    txtAnswer.Text = "0"
    ArithmeticProcess = "/"


End Sub


Private Sub btnEquals_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEquals.Click
    SecondNumber = Val(txtAnswer.Text)
    If ArithmeticProcess = "+" Then
        AnswerNumber = FirstNumber + SecondNumber
    End If
    If ArithmeticProcess = "-" Then
        AnswerNumber = FirstNumber - SecondNumber
    End If
    If ArithmeticProcess = "X" Then
        AnswerNumber = FirstNumber * SecondNumber
    End If
    If ArithmeticProcess = "/" Then
        AnswerNumber = FirstNumber / SecondNumber
    End If
    txtAnswer.Text = AnswerNumber
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    Me.txtAnswer.Clear()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Start by setting [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you'll find you have a few other things to correct while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Try ... Catch block to catch exceptions when calculating.

```
Try
  answerNumber = firstNumber / secondNumber
Catch ex As OverflowException
  MsgBox("cannot divide by 0")
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch an error, you need to validate the input....

C#

```
if (SecondNumber == 0) 
{
//you are trying to divide by 0
}
```

VB.NET

```
If SecondNumber = 0 Then
   //you are trying to divide by 0
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Try function as a catch all around the code and also a 'zero catcher'

```
Try
 ''''your code

Catch ex As OverflowException
  MsgBox("Sorry Something went wrong")
End Try
```

and stop the '0' begin run...

```
  If ArithmeticProcess = "/" Then
If SecondNumber <> 0 Then
 MsgBox("You cannot divide by Zero")

Else
            AnswerNumber = FirstNumber / SecondNumber
        End If
   End If
```